# LSI RAID controller errors on DB import - How to troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, oracle, rhel5, hardware-raid

We're running an import of a database dump on an Oracle system - (RHEL 5.9, 2.6.18-348.6.1.el5). The import does not complete, eventually erroring-out with:

```
ORA-15080: synchronous I/O operation to a disk failed
WARNING: failed to write mirror side 1 of virtual extent 248 logical extent 0 of file 280 in group 1 on disk 1 allocation unit 986
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/dbprod/DBPROD/trace/DBPROD_lgwr_24520.trc:
ORA-00345: redo log write error block 509314 count 2023
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '+DATA/dbprod/redo01.log'
ORA-15081: failed to submit an I/O operation to a disk
ORA-15081: failed to submit an I/O operation to a disk
```

There are corresponding errors in the ring buffer and `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: build_ld_io  error, sge_count = 51
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: Err returned from build_and_issue_cmd
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: build_ld_io  error, sge_count = 51
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: Err returned from build_and_issue_cmd
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: build_ld_io  error, sge_count = 51
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: megasas: Err returned from build_and_issue_cmd
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: sd 0:2:1:0: timing out command, waited 360s
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: sd 0:2:1:0: Unhandled error code
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: sd 0:2:1:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x06000000
Jun 12 18:54:42 db1-test kernel: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT,SUGGEST_OK
```

The drive array containing the import is a 10-disk SAS array in RAID 1+0 using 300GB 10k disks. The RAID controller is an [LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-8i](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9260-8i.aspx). No disk or adapter errors are reported via MegaCLI.

- Is this a hardware issue?
- Is there any way to troubleshoot? The RAID controller status is fine. The disks and logical drives report healthy.
- Is this a Linux OS or tuning issue? I'll try with different I/O schedulers to be sure. [CFQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ) is default.

---

**Edit:**

Other schedulers have been tried with the same result. **There *is* a [third-party (Vormetric) filesystem encryption module](http://www.vormetric.com/products/encryption/file-encryption) running in this setup.** Removing it allows the import to complete. So now I'm wondering if this is a deficiency in the module or if it is triggering a bad condition in the LSI driver.

---

*During the import, we're hitting 14,000 write IOPS.*
[image]

*In recent attempts, the system stalls entirely with the following on the console.*
[image]

*Last `top` output before freeze.*
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear - the Raid controller says the drives are OK? What does LSI support say? Given that this is a VERY obvious "RAID / OS intergation" issue, they would be my first choice to ask. If the discs ARE broken, at least their tools should say so - that is the job of a raid controller.

Comment: This only seems to occur during the database import. Normal activity is unaffected.

Comment: from the code in the megaraid driver, it seems to be overrunning some buffer while preparing a command to the logical drive. Try updating the controller's firmware, the driver and asking LSI support - in this order.

Comment: The error means that the driver got a request with more SG entries than supported by hardware; this may be caused by bugs in the block IO stack. [A similar bug in RHEL5 involving dm](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=512387) was claimed to be fixed; there was also [a possibly related bug in upstream Linux dm](http://osdir.com/ml/dm-devel/2010-11/msg00166.html).

Comment: @syneticon-dj Firmware was updated... I did get screenshots from watching logs/console in realtime, though. `dmsetup` was sitting at the top of the process resource utilization list.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I ran across the RHEL notes, but didn't make the dm connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately [Sergey](https://serverfault.com/questions/515533/lsi-raid-controller-errors-on-db-import-how-to-troubleshoot#comment583981_515533) is right - this is a driver problem. But let's check things out first:

First off you'll want to use the deadline I/O scheduler rather than CFQ. `deadline`, as its name implies, ensures that all IOPs complete in a timely manner.

Grab the events from the megaraid card:

```
megacli -adpeventlog -getevents -f /tmp/megaraid-$(date +%F_%T) -aALL
```

Check the SMART data on the disks (you will need to build a new smartmontools for this to work):

```
# megacli -pdlist -a0 |grep 'Device Id'
Device Id: 10
Device Id: 9

# smartctl -a /dev/sda -d megaraid,9
«…»
# smartctl -a /dev/sda -d megaraid,10
«…»
```

If everything looks OK, go ahead and try out the [latest driver from LSI](http://www.lsi.com/support/Pages/Download-Results.aspx?productcode=P00066&assettype=0&component=Storage%20Component&productfamily=RAID%20Controllers&productname=MegaRAID%20SAS%209260-8i).

---

> There is a third-party (Vormetric) filesystem encryption module running in this setup. Removing it allows the import to complete. So now I'm wondering if this is a deficiency in the module or if it is triggering a bad condition in the LSI driver.

The Voretric module is likely doing something incompatible, yes. I would start by talking with them about how their module is screwing up your system under high load.

Comment: I tried with `deadline` and `noop`. Both crashed or hung the system. I've left things at `deadline`. Firmware is current. Driver really shouldn't be changed due to other factors with the EL5.9 build.

Comment: See edit about about the encryption filesystem layer being used.