# Large write with dd fail on RAID-5

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5, dd

I have a server with a RAID controller which connects to a JBOD over SAS.
JBOD is populated with 16 SAS-HDDs of 3TB (8 of one make and 8 of other, same rpm).
I have configured 3 logical drives with RAID-5, each having 5 physical HDDs (+1 as hot-spare).

Now to test it out, i run the following script:

```
for i in 1 10 50 100 1000
 do for j in a b c
  do dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd$j bs=1G count=$i
 done
done
```

Everytime i run this script, it runs fine for the count=1,10 and 50.

But with 100G, writes on virtual drives crash randomly. Meaning, sometimes write on /dev/sda gets completed without and error but crashes for /dev/sdb. Sometimes writes on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb complete but fails on /dev/sdc.

I suspect that my RAID card might be faulty because i have already tested my harddisks individually by attaching them directly to the server and running "dd" on full 3TB.

What do you guys suggest?

**EDIT**:

**Server motherboard make/model**: SuperMicro X8DTH-6F
**RAID controller**: LSI MegaRaid SAS 9285-8e with BBU
**JBOD**: SuperMicro JBOD SC836E26-R1200B
**SAS HDDs**: 3.5", 6Gbps SAS, 3TB, 7200rpm  ( 8x - Seagate ST3000NM0023, 8x - Hitachi Ultrastar 7K3000
**OS**: Scientific Linux 6.3

JBOD is connected to raid controller through a 6Gbps SAS cable.

**EDIT 2**:
Here is the text from /var/log/messages:

```
May  1 18:14:41 fileserver udevd[875]: worker [4083] unexpectedly returned with status 0x0100
May  1 18:14:41 fileserver udevd[875]: worker [4083] failed while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:2:0/0:2:0:0/block/sda'
May  1 18:14:43 fileserver kernel: megasas: Found FW in FAULT state, will reset adapter.
May  1 18:14:43 fileserver kernel: megaraid_sas: resetting fusion adapter.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task dd:4144 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: dd            D 000000000000000d     0  4144   4132 0x00000004
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff88060c513bf8 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 ffffea0015a3a8c0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff88062d837938 ffff88062d837848 ffff88062ce06ea0 ffff88062ce06ea0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff8806133385f8 ffff88060c513fd8 000000000000fb88 ffff8806133385f8
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811140c0>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fdfc3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811140fd>] sync_page+0x3d/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fe97f>] __wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x90
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81114333>] wait_on_page_bit+0x73/0x80
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81092110>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8112a835>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x25/0x40
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811147ab>] wait_on_page_writeback_range+0xfb/0x190
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8111486f>] filemap_fdatawait+0x2f/0x40
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81114e94>] filemap_write_and_wait+0x44/0x60
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4634>] __sync_blockdev+0x24/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4673>] sync_blockdev+0x13/0x20
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b47f8>] __blkdev_put+0x178/0x1b0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b9403>] ? fsnotify+0x113/0x160
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4840>] blkdev_put+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4883>] blkdev_close+0x33/0x60
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117c935>] __fput+0xf5/0x210
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117ca75>] fput+0x25/0x30
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117849d>] filp_close+0x5d/0x90
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178575>] sys_close+0xa5/0x100
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task scsi_id:4145 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: scsi_id       D 0000000000000013     0  4145      1 0x00000000
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1a145c18 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 ffff880c00000002
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1a145be8 00007f9200000066 00000000007fffff ffffffff81fc7990
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2ee3b098 ffff880c1a145fd8 000000000000fb88 ffff880c2ee3b098
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fee8e>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13e/0x180
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8125ee50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fed2b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4958>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3c0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cd0>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cc0>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4d41>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117888a>] __dentry_open+0x10a/0x360
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121c262>] ? selinux_inode_permission+0x72/0xb0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121429f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178bf4>] nameidata_to_filp+0x54/0x70
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8118c100>] do_filp_open+0x6c0/0xd60
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8104452c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff812718b1>] ? cpumask_any_but+0x31/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811449a0>] ? unmap_region+0x110/0x130
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81198182>] ? alloc_fd+0x92/0x160
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178639>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x140
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178750>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task fdisk:4176 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: fdisk         D 0000000000000013     0  4176   4147 0x00000004
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2f56dc18 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 ffff880c30802078
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2f56dbe8 ffff880c00000721 00000000007fffff ffffffff81fc8368
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1d6af058 ffff880c2f56dfd8 000000000000fb88 ffff880c1d6af058
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fee8e>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13e/0x180
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8125ee50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fed2b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4958>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3c0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cd0>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cc0>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4d41>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117888a>] __dentry_open+0x10a/0x360
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121c262>] ? selinux_inode_permission+0x72/0xb0
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121429f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178bf4>] nameidata_to_filp+0x54/0x70
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8118c100>] do_filp_open+0x6c0/0xd60
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8104452c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811e06c5>] ? pde_users_dec+0x25/0x60
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81198182>] ? alloc_fd+0x92/0x160
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178639>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x140
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178750>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
May  1 18:15:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:16:27 fileserver kernel: megaraid_sas: Diag reset adapter never cleared!
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task dd:4144 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: dd            D 000000000000000d     0  4144   4132 0x00000004
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff88060c513bf8 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 ffffea0015a3a8c0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff88062d837938 ffff88062d837848 ffff88062ce06ea0 ffff88062ce06ea0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff8806133385f8 ffff88060c513fd8 000000000000fb88 ffff8806133385f8
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811140c0>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fdfc3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811140fd>] sync_page+0x3d/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fe97f>] __wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x90
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81114333>] wait_on_page_bit+0x73/0x80
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81092110>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8112a835>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x25/0x40
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811147ab>] wait_on_page_writeback_range+0xfb/0x190
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8111486f>] filemap_fdatawait+0x2f/0x40
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81114e94>] filemap_write_and_wait+0x44/0x60
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4634>] __sync_blockdev+0x24/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4673>] sync_blockdev+0x13/0x20
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b47f8>] __blkdev_put+0x178/0x1b0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b9403>] ? fsnotify+0x113/0x160
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4840>] blkdev_put+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4883>] blkdev_close+0x33/0x60
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117c935>] __fput+0xf5/0x210
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117ca75>] fput+0x25/0x30
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117849d>] filp_close+0x5d/0x90
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178575>] sys_close+0xa5/0x100
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task scsi_id:4145 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: scsi_id       D 0000000000000013     0  4145      1 0x00000000
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1a145c18 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 ffff880c00000002
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1a145be8 00007f9200000066 00000000007fffff ffffffff81fc7990
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2ee3b098 ffff880c1a145fd8 000000000000fb88 ffff880c2ee3b098
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fee8e>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13e/0x180
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8125ee50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fed2b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4958>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3c0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cd0>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cc0>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4d41>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117888a>] __dentry_open+0x10a/0x360
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121c262>] ? selinux_inode_permission+0x72/0xb0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121429f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178bf4>] nameidata_to_filp+0x54/0x70
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8118c100>] do_filp_open+0x6c0/0xd60
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8104452c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff812718b1>] ? cpumask_any_but+0x31/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811449a0>] ? unmap_region+0x110/0x130
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81198182>] ? alloc_fd+0x92/0x160
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178639>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x140
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178750>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: INFO: task fdisk:4176 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: fdisk         D 0000000000000013     0  4176   4147 0x00000004
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2f56dc18 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 ffff880c30802078
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c2f56dbe8 ffff880c00000721 00000000007fffff ffffffff81fc8368
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: ffff880c1d6af058 ffff880c2f56dfd8 000000000000fb88 ffff880c1d6af058
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: Call Trace:
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fee8e>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13e/0x180
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8125ee50>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff814fed2b>] mutex_lock+0x2b/0x50
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4958>] __blkdev_get+0x68/0x3c0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cd0>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4cc0>] blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b4d41>] blkdev_open+0x71/0xc0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8117888a>] __dentry_open+0x10a/0x360
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121c262>] ? selinux_inode_permission+0x72/0xb0
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8121429f>] ? security_inode_permission+0x1f/0x30
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178bf4>] nameidata_to_filp+0x54/0x70
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8118c100>] do_filp_open+0x6c0/0xd60
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8104452c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff811e06c5>] ? pde_users_dec+0x25/0x60
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81198182>] ? alloc_fd+0x92/0x160
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178639>] do_sys_open+0x69/0x140
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff81178750>] sys_open+0x20/0x30
May  1 18:17:17 fileserver kernel: [<ffffffff8100b0f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
May  1 18:18:11 fileserver kernel: megaraid_sas: Diag reset adapter never cleared!
...
...
```

I can't make anything of it, its a cry for help!

Comment: Server make/model? Enclosure make/model? Disk makes/models? RAID controller make/model? Operating system/version/distribution? Server specifications? Cabling arrangement?

Comment: "but crashes for /dev/sdb" Stop making up terms. Unless `dd` itself actually crashed. Show the errors from the console, dmesg and the RAID controller.

Comment: Ah, Supermicro... Have you checked firmware of the related components?

Comment: @MikeyB Sorry, TIL. There is no error on console, i'll add the output of dmesg shortly. BTW how do i check errors from RAID controller?

Comment: @ewwhite i haven't updates any firmware yet, will do that.

Comment: Read through [my answer here](http://serverfault.com/questions/515533/lsi-raid-controller-errors-on-db-import-how-to-troubleshoot/515843#515843) (also, are you getting the same errors?) as I show how to dump the event log from the MegaRAID card.

Comment: @MikeyB Yeah, the OP in the question you linked didn't know what he was talking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that Scientific Linux 6.3 on Supermicro servers has some issues with PCIe.
A friend suggested to add the following two options to grub:

1. pcie_aspm=off
2. disable_msi=1

After booting with these options, everything started working fine.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Ropey hardware, by which I mean, hardware that doesn't precisely honour the spec, and a kernel that's under-tolerant of this imprecision.  Happens a lot, especially with budget kit and/or consumer-grade parts.  If you're confident in your findings, ditch **either** SuperMicro **or** Scientific Linux.  Personally, I'd ditch the hardware manufacturer.  And thanks for coming back and posting the answer you found; please accept it as soon as the system will let you do so.

Comment: @MadHatter thanks, i'll try different manufacturer next time.